# VBA Troubles in running two functions

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a VBA tool where I am extracting names of all the files in a folder in excel (call it output A). Thereafter, I am doing some processing on the file names to extract a part of it (call it output B). (My tool is working fine till here)
After this, I want to extract only the unique values from output B. I am facing problem in this step.

Code for getting output A:

```
Sub GetFileNames()

Dim xRow As Long
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$

InitialFoldr$ = "G:\" '<<< Startup folder to begin searching from

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
    .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
    .Show
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C11").Activate

    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)
        Do While xFname$ <> ""
            ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = xFname$
            xRow = xRow + 1
            xFname$ = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End With
getunique
End Sub
```

Code for generating Output B:

```
Sub getunique()
Range("F11:F70").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("C3"), Unique:=True
End Sub
```

Independently, both the functions are running fine. But when I am trying to run them together, I am facing problems.

I created two separate macros. When I run the second macro, the list generated (output A) gets automatically cleared.

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: You use C11, C3, and F11:F70 in your code. At least for me it's not clear how they work together.

Comment: What's in `Range("F11:F70")` you're pasting the file names in to column C

Comment: It is being cleared because you are copying the unique filtered range F11:F70  to C3, which in turn is overwriting output A in Cells C11 and down. You need to change the location of where Output B is to be copied.

Comment: Ritika, you need to work with dynamic ranges. `ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = xFname$`. Define your starting cell and then find the last row to identify the range. Similarly you need to define the range for Output B.

Comment: So, I am extracting the names of the files (output A) C11 onwards. In f11:f70, I have processed the names extracted in C11 (and onwards) to extract a string from those names. Thereafter, I am trying to pick only unique values from f11:f70 and paste in c3. Given that there are only 4 unique values, it won't overwrite my file name starting C11.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Your second function refers to `ActiveSheet` ("Sheet1" in this case). Ideally you should always fully qualify your ranges, i.e.: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3")`, though i personally prefer to asign to variables:

```
Dim WB as Workbook : Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Dim WS as Worksheet : Set WS = WB.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Then you can easily reuse them later:

```
With WS
    .Range("F11:F70").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Range("D3"), Unique:=True
End With
```

Anyway, that and the fact you are trying to write to the same column, doesn't help...

Try the below, assuming you have `"Sheet2"`:

```
Sub getunique()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F11:F70").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3"), Unique:=True
End
```

Alternatively, change `CopyToRange:=Range("C3")` to a different column should still work.

**EDIT**
The error you are getting is because you don't really have anything in `Range("F11:F70")` ... change the advancedfilter to point to the range where you collecting the filenames `Range("C11:C70")`.

Comment: Hi DarXyde, Thank you for the help, but it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: Even when I try to run it independently, it is not working as expected. With numbers, it works perfectly, with strings, it just copies all the strings without removing the duplicate values. TIA

Comment: The problem is that you don't really have anything in `Range("F11:F70")` ... change the advancedfilter to point to the range where you collecting the filenames `Range("C11:C70")`. Will update the answer as well to reflect this.

Comment: Not quite sure just this 2 steps as they are will get you what you need. As you are listing items from folders, they would be already unique values anyways... unless in `Range("F11:F70")` you are supposed to have some formulas that trim down your results from `Range("C11:C70")` ? Regardless of this, don't think is a good idea to copy with the advancedfilter over the same range your filtering from...